# search query in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a search query to work in laravel 5, right now i just want it to pull exact match because i'm just desperate to get it to work, but eventually i want to find these 2 matching numbers in everything string of numbers that contains those 2.  I tried various ways, but this is the latest way i attempted.
FWI the searchbar is in my layout.
This is in layout:

```
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'GET', 'url' => 'executeSearch')) !!}
        @include('Partials.search_form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

my searchbar form :

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('SEARCH:') !!}
    {!! Form::text( 'search', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
'        placeholder' =>'(NSN or PN)', 'size' => '20']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('executeSearch', 'SearchController@executeSearch', function()
{
    $search = Input::get('search');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['search'] = $search;
    DB::select('select * from fsgdatas where fsg_number = ?', array($search));

return('SearchController@executeSearch');

});
```

This is my controller

```
public function executeSearch()
{


    return View('Search_views.searchresults',compact('search'));
}
```

this is the searchresult view:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('SEARCH:') !!}
    {!! Form::text( 'search', null, ['class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' =>'(NSN or PN)', 'size' => '20']) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>

<p>{{$name}}</p>
@endsection
```

This is my error:
`Undefined variable: name (View: /vagrant/leonis/resources/views/Search_views/searchresults.blade.php)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the `name` variable into the view.  You are only passing `search`...

```
return View('Search_views.searchresults',compact('search'));
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo.  I had right the first time but, i was trying to change my code back to way i thought would work the best.  its the same error though `Undefined variable: search (View: /vagrant/leonis/resources/views/Search_views/searchresults.blade.php)`

Comment: Sorry, try moving your code from the route to the controller

Comment: I tied that as well.  it doesn't find the input, which is why i tried it in routes haha.  this is error i will get it `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found`

Comment: Try adding this at the top of the file to use the Input class

Comment: Darn return button - Try this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`

Comment: now it's saying it can't find the database `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found`

Comment: this is fustrating because this database absolutely exist haha.  Thanks for your patience

Comment: Same thing here.  Make sure you import all your necessary classes at the top. Put `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` at the top